# Browser integration testing with web3.js for dApps

Tags: web3js, metamask, contract-debugging

What are the practices to test web3.js codebase in a wwv browser using testrpc chain? Basically emulating Metamask and having Selenium automation to sign the transactions.

Answer (score 1):

We can invoke web3 js API functions from the UI. The node packages for the web3 js need to be installed in the local testrpc local blockchain environment. If you want to invoke Metamask from the browser with in your web application you can integrate the metamask extension through nodejs modules. It is not clear how do you want to use selenium to sign the transactions. Could you please elaborate.